# bash array multiplication using bc

Tags: bash, bc, bash-array

I am trying to multiply array values with values derived from the multiplication of a loop index using bc.

```
#!/bin/bash
n=10.0
bw=(1e-3 2.5e-4 1.11e-4 6.25e-5 4.0e-5 2.78e-5 2.04e-5 1.56e-5 1.29e-5 1.23e-5 1.0e-5)
for k in {1..11};do
    a=$(echo "$n * $k" | bc)
    echo "A is  $a"
    arn=${bw[k-1]}
    echo "Arn is  $arn"
    b=$(echo "$arn * $a" | bc -l)
    echo "b is $b"
    #echo $a $b
done
```

I am able to echo the array values by assigning it to a new variable within the loop, but when I use that to multiply using `bc`, I get `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`.
I searched for clues and tried some but none helped. The expected output is as follows.

```
10  1.00E-02
20  5.00E-03
30  3.33E-03
40  2.50E-03
50  2.00E-03
60  1.67E-03
70  1.43E-03
80  1.25E-03
90  1.16E-03
100 1.23E-03
110 1.10E-03
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bc` doesn't support the scientific format. Use something that does.

For example, Perl:

```
    a=$(perl -e "print $n * $k" )
    arn=${bw[k-1]}
    b=$(perl -e "printf '%.2E', $arn * $a")
    echo $a $b
```

Output:

```
10 1.00E-02
20 5.00E-03
30 3.33E-03
40 2.50E-03
50 2.00E-03
60 1.67E-03
70 1.43E-03
80 1.25E-03
90 1.16E-03
100 1.23E-03
110 1.10E-03
```

Answer (score 3):

Replacing OP's `for` loop with a single `awk` script:

```
awk -v n="$n" '                             # assign awk variable "n" the value of OS variable "n"
{ k++                                       # increment counter (initially == 0)
  printf "%s %0.2E\n",(k*n),($1*k*n)        # print output
}
' < <(printf "%s\n" "${bw[@]}")             # print each bw[] entry on a separate line
```

This generates:

```
10 1.00E-02
20 5.00E-03
30 3.33E-03
40 2.50E-03
50 2.00E-03
60 1.67E-03
70 1.43E-03
80 1.25E-03
90 1.16E-03
100 1.23E-03
110 1.10E-03
```

Answer (score 2):

`bc` doesn't support scientific notation, but you could replace `e` with `*10^` to get the result.

```
$ printf 'print k+=10, " ", k*%s, "\n"\n' "${bw[@]/[eE]/*10^}" | bc -l
10 .01000000000000000000
20 .00500000000000000000
30 .00333000000000000000
40 .00250000000000000000
50 .00200000000000000000
60 .00166800000000000000
70 .00142800000000000000
80 .00124800000000000000
90 .00116100000000000000
100 .00123000000000000000
110 .00110000000000000000
```

(here assuming GNU `bc` for its `print` extension).

If the point of using `bc` is that you want arbitrary precision, you could use `perl`'s `bignum` module for that:

```
$ perl -Mbignum -e 'for $i (@ARGV) {printf "%-3d %.2E\n", $k += 10, $i * $k}' -- "${bw[@]}"
10  1.00E-02
20  5.00E-03
30  3.33E-03
40  2.50E-03
50  2.00E-03
60  1.67E-03
70  1.43E-03
80  1.25E-03
90  1.16E-03
100 1.23E-03
110 1.10E-03
```

If you don't need arbitrary precision, then it would be easier to switch to a shell with floating point support like zsh, ksh93 or yash.

A lot of the syntax in that script such as `array=(...)` or `{1..11}` actually come from zsh, borrowed by bash years later.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
bw=(
  1e-3     2.5e-4   1.11e-4  6.25e-5
  4.0e-5   2.78e-5  2.04e-5  1.56e-5
  1.29e-5  1.23e-5  1.0e-5
)
k=0
for i ($bw) printf '%-3d %.2E\n' k+=10 'k*i'
```